# Application Error - The connection to the server was unsuccesful.(http://localhost:8101)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

When I run my ionic app in android device, it shows an error

**Application Error

 The connection to the server was unsuccesful.(http://localhost:8101)**

I run with the command
 **ionic cordova run android -lc**

How i can fix this error? why this error occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option in this scenario is to not pass the -l which is for livereload functionality. So just run:

```
ionic cordova run android
```

This will then compile the apk and deploy it to your phone, but won't run a web server to watch for changes.

You can still debug with Chrome in this scenario, but if you make a change to the markup and press save it won't automatically reload the app with that change. You would need to run `ionic cordova run android` again to rebuild and deploy it to your phone.

On the plus side 1: after the first deploy, subsequent builds are much faster, as a gradle server is started.

On the plus side 2: if you disconnect your USB then you can still use your app. With a livereload deployed app it breaks once you disconnect.

I would actually really like to solve your problem as well. As I move around coworking spaces sometimes it seems that the network is locked down somehow and just is blocking certain ports. I haven't figured out exactly why or if there is a workaround for this.